# XAMPP NOT WORKING! - OS X Yosemite

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite

I was working with XAMPP 1.8.3-3 on OS X Mavericks. After upgrading to Yosemite Mysql server stopped working. And an upgrade to XAMPP 1.8.3-5 fixed the problem and mysql server starts working.

Now the entire database list is showing on phpmyadmin, but no access to the tables. Its showing “#1146 - Table ‘DB_NAME.TABLE_NAME’ doesn’t exist”.

Unfortunately I don't have any DB backup!

I have the entire XAMPP folder backup. So how I can able to retrieve the mysql tables?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Since I can't find any info I've decided to just recreate the whole thing. Problem is, I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2):

just type /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
 in terminal then start xampp

Comment: I don't have a problem with starting mysql server actually! I'm not able to restore my older mysql tables.

Answer (score 1):

you can restore if you have all the mysql folders from XAMPP folder. (check `/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql` in backup)
if you have var/mysql folder, open and look for database names you had earlier.

there is a separate folder for each database you had earlier. open the folder and it will contain lots of files with table names.

if your old table engine is InnoDB you will see 2 files. with `.frm` and `.ibd` extensions.

or if you had MyISM it will contain three file per table which has `.frm`, `.MYD` and `.MYI` extensions.

after you verify you have all the required files in backup, you can start restoring them.

1. stop mysql
2. copy required database folder completely and paste it to currently installed folder. (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/)
3. start mysql

to restore web files, open htdocs folder in backup and copy required site folder to currentely xampp installed htdocs folder.

This solution worked for me. Good Luck !

Comment: I have tried all these! still the same! shows the table list, but I'm not able to access it, returns an error “#1146 - Table ‘DB_NAME.TABLE_NAME’ doesn’t exist”.

Comment: The problem is the privellige on the folder sin /var/mysql folders. The user should be "_mysql.

Comment: Tried that too! still the same!

Comment: Hi @vivekrajns have you gotten this sorted out? I have the same issue; files are there, permissions are ok, but I can't access table data.

Comment: @GabbyL1003 nope! not yet! Still I'm waiting for a solution!

Comment: Guys can you give 777 permission for all db files for test? and check.

Comment: I noticed it only happened for 2 of my tables which were in InnoDB (the others were MyISAM). @HackerGK will try that with the next database with this issue; I've only had to rework one project so far and I ended up restoring from a dump of the production database.

Comment: Ah you get same problem as mine. i also got two InnoDB which is not loading. i tried with Ampp software with same recovery process and got one table worked and other loosed. you can try that too..

Answer (score 0):

Do a clean install. See my answer for my own question. [xampp mysql server not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593238/xampp-mysql-server-not-starting/26599454#26599454). The bad part is that I'm not sure if it will save your database the way I explained. What you might try is going to xampp > xamppfiles > var > mysql > 'your database name' and making a copy of the database folder on your desktop and moving it back once you reinstall it. I tried and I think it might have worked had I changed the file permissions. You can also try experimenting to see if it preserves the database if you do this. I would do some serious testing if you really want to save your database before doing this.

Comment: Already tried a clean install as well as permission change, unfortunately that is also not working!