# xampp mysql server not starting

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Help please I can't start the sql database server in xampp. This was after upgrading to os x Yosemite. This is the error message I get for phpmyadmin:

Welcome to phpMyAdmin

Error
MySQL said: Documentation

## 2002 - No such file or directory

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

Thank you so much!
Here is the command I tried in terminal (which I got from another person on stack overflow who seemed to have a similar problem):

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
```

Here was the error message:

```
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/imac.local.pid).
```

sql conf file:

```
# Example MySQL config file for medium systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (32M - 64M) where MySQL plays
# an important part, or systems up to 128M where MySQL is used together with
# other programs (such as a web server)
#
# You can copy this file to
# /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
user = mysql
port=3306
socket      = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/mysql/plugin/

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
# commented in by xampp security
#skip-networking
skip-networking

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
tmpdir = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/mysql
#log-update     = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
# Deprecated in 5.6
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

!include /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/mysql/my.cnf
```

Comment: Paste your configuration file. Has the `mysqld` daemon started?

Comment: Please read the tag summary before blindly throwing tags onto your question.

Comment: what is `mysqld`? You may want to view the question again since I have updated it with more information. Thanks!

Comment: I did a clean reinstall everything is fine! Thank you all :-)

Answer (score 0):

For all of you to know I ended up doing a fresh reinstall of xampp. It now works fine! Here was what I did:

- backup files and database (if possible)
- quit 'manager os x'
- run the uninstaller
- delete the xampp folder
- download xampp from the site
- Run the installer for xampp
- run security program in terminal
- move your stuff back to the xampp folder

All in all I found that xampp (1.8.3-5) is compatible with OS X Yosemite.