# Mysql won't start after upgrading Mac OS X Yosemite (Mac OS 10.10)

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-yosemite

Right after upgrading to Mac OS Yosemite (10.10), my Mysql won't start anymore. Instead I get

```
MacBook-Pro:/ user$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
Starting MySQL 
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/wireless.ubc.ca.pid).
```

I tried to check version number but I also get the following error

```
MacBook-Pro:/ user$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -v
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I found lots of people having problems with XAMPP [not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26438068/xampp-not-working-os-x-yosemite) after Yosemite install, Also eclipse not working. I see many people just say reinstall. Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't yet updated to Yosemite yet but I had this link saved when I do:

[Get Apache, MySQL, PHP and phpMyAdmin working on OSX 10.10 Yosemite](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/)

This specific line may do some good:

```
sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

But check the whole post and let me know if it helps!

Good luck!

Comment: For me, install of mysql on Yosemite failed with an error and the /tmp dir does not have a sock file.

Comment: I wish I saw that earlier. I did not try that. I ended up reinstalling. Yet I do recall that I also did not have that sock file in the /tmp directory.

Comment: The synthetic link to the socket wasn't the startup issue for me, rather it was that the /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM script (in conjunction with it's preference pane) doesn't work anymore.  To fix MySQL launch at startup, the link @marcelo-gaia posted above was invaluable, in particular, the /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql/mysql.plist

Comment: Glad that this helped :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so this installation is needed. I got the same issue when I upgraded to Yosemite.

I tried to run the mysql server through command line but it failed, saying

> Starting MySQL
>   .... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Bilals-MacBook-Pro.local.pid).

I went in preferences and clicked mysql there, and it was stopped. Start mysql from preferences which will ask for root password, and it worked :)

Comment: Glad, this helped someone :)

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks for this perfectly simple solution!

Answer (score 3):

After updating MySQL I also for some reason have to change the permissions of the MySQL dir for it to work. The installer always changes the permissions to root.

```
chown -R _mysql:wheel /usr/local/mysql-5.6.21-osx10.8-x86_64/
```

Comment: I am not talking about updating MySQL. I am talking about if MySQL is already installed then you update Yosemite and now MySQL no longer starts.

Comment: I accidentally changed the permission of the mysql folder because of the user right recommendations by Homebrew: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/El_Capitan_and_Homebrew.md
The command from above fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers worked for me.  I reinstalled mysql using homebrew and it worked.

http://blog.joefallon.net/2013/10/install-mysql-on-mac-osx-using-homebrew/