# Install MySQL and create a database on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-yosemite

I want to install MySQL on Mac OS X Yosemite, create a new user, then create a new database called "my_database".  How can I do this?

**What I've tried:**

1. From command line, `brew install mysql`. This succeeds and downloads
   MySQL to `/usr/local/bin/mysql`.
2. Log into MySQL `mysql -u root`.

**I get an error in Step 2:**

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. I ran `ps ax | grep mysql` which showed no MySQL processes were running. Then I ran `sudo /usr/local/bin/mysql start` but I get the same `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL ...`.

Comment: I use MacPorts, so not sure how you'll do it, but you need to start the server first. Typically, use the `launchctl` command.

Comment: Have you tried starting the mysql process using `sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start`, not sure if brew adds this though. You should also be able to start the server by going to `/usr/local/bin/mysql/support-files` and then running `mysql.server start`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to update your path to the mysql socket.

sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock

I think this was already answered here:
[Mysql won't start after upgrading Mac OS X Yosemite (Mac OS 10.10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619672/mysql-wont-start-after-upgrading-mac-os-x-yosemite-mac-os-10-10)